# Is there a way to scan each pixel of a photo to look for coordinates with python? ( find RA and Dec coordinates through pixels )

Tags: python, astronomy

I was wondering if there was a way to use python to look through an image to find coordinates. Basically I just need to find the pixel values ( x,y ) for a target star by matching it to its correct right ascension and declination values. However, I have zero idea how to do this, so I thought I'd ask. I'd really appreciate any help or guidance. Thank you!

Comment: If you create a mapping between integer pixel co-ordinates and the angles, then you can calculate the integer values from the angles. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: To calculate this you'll probably need the angle of the camera/telescope along with the angle of view.

Comment: Not at all. Most of the images I get, it doesn't include that information.

Comment: What information do you have? If you don't have any positional or angle information you won't be able to calculate any co-ordinates, and will probably have to use some kind of pattern matching, which might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I mean I already have the coordinates from the image. Through a website called nova.astrometry.net. It plate solves the image, but I just needed to know if theres a way to open the image then get the pixel coordinates. Other than that, I have things like location ( lat, long ), time and date, pixel binning, image scale, notes, and a few other things.

Comment: I've had a look at that website and it has the image centre and pixel scale which should be sufficient. So you can do something like `x = (t_ra - RA) / ps + W / 2`, where `x` is the x coord, `t_ra` is the star RA, `RA` is the centre RA, `ps` is the pixel scale and `W` is the image width. And there will be a similar equation for `y`. I'll write up a proper answer with code.

Answer (score 0):

If we have the image centre in degrees such as (RA, Dec) and the pixel scale with units (deg/px) then we can calculate the pixel co-ordinates as follows:

```py
img = <2D image array>

t_ra = <target star RA in degrees>
t_dec = <target star Dec in degrees>
c_ra = <image centre RA>
c_dec = <image centre Dec>
ps = <pixel scale in deg/px>

H, W = img.shape
x = int((t_ra - c_ra) / ps + W / 2)
y = int((t_dec - c_dec) / ps + H / 2)

# To extract a small square patch from the image
patch_size = 50
img_patch = img[x - patch_size:x + patch_size, y - patch_size:y + patch_size]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to convert a FITS image to a 2D image array? Sorry for all the questions. Thanks!

Comment: According to the [FITS website](https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_libraries.html) there are four Python libraries that can read FITS image data, of which two are more up-to-date, so take your pick as to which will be best for you: [`fitsio`](https://pypi.org/project/fitsio/) and [`astropy`](https://pypi.org/project/astropy/).

Comment: Thanks, I have checked out astropy, but I think there might be a problem with my images. I don't have an HDU header in my images. Everything they list in the docs results in an index error. Gonna keep looking. Thank you!